# Element destroy() of Mootools 1.3 always fails in IE

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools1.2

I just upgraded my code to 1.3 from 1.2.4. Oftentimes, an element has been destroyed, but its events will still be called. However, all those Element methods which used to be attached to the elements have been cleaned. This issue only happens in IE.

Has anyone experienced similar upgrading issue?

Comment: Please create a test-case on jsfiddle.net, so others can play around with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a known and reported bug. More information can be found here:
https://mootools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/2706/tickets/1090-destroying-element-with-duplicate-event-handlers-throws-error-in-ie8

Comment: Also, I found out, if I avoid using custom events and only use element events, it works fine, because we say "destroy", it will clean the element events, but some custom events still live.